# Is Mathematica 8 compatible with Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: version-8, mac-os-x

Does anyone know if *Mathematica 8* works with *OS X 10.9*?

Comment: 9 is, but I don't have 8 handy to check.

Comment: 8 works fine with 10.9

Comment: 8.0.4 works fine here on 10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to *OS X 10.9* and have tested out *Mathematica 8* for several days. Can't say it was comprehensive, but so far it seems to be working, so I think the answer to my question is yes.

Answer (score 7):

Let's put the answers together:

- Version 9.0.1 is compatible (acl, halirutan)
- Version 8.0.4 seems compatible too (bill s, Szabolcs)